# Read line in C++ till EOF

Tags: c++, cin, eof

I'm writing a function that reads line by line from `cin` and returns when it sees `;` character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int read_cmd(char *cmd)
{
    cout << "Please enter a string: \n";
    cmd[0]='\0';

    while(1){
        char currentLine[10000];
        currentLine[0]='\0';
        cin.getline(currentLine,10000);
        if (strcmp(currentLine,";")==0){
            break;
        }
        strcat(cmd, "\n");
        strcat(cmd, currentLine);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char cmd[1000];
    while (1){
        read_cmd(cmd);
        cout<< cmd << endl;
    }
}
```

I then tested it using text fed from another file via pipe. 
./read_cmd < test_file

contents of test_file:

```
line 1
line 2
;
```

This outputs results just fine, however it gives me a segmentation fault at the end. Is there a way for `cin` to check if it's coming across an EOF and terminates?

Comment: Did you read the manual page for `getline`?

Comment: Something like `while(getline(cin,line))` should do well.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest the use of the `string` object for something like this, that way you're not wasting space, as well as ensuring that you have enouch space. You can also do it without a loop.

```
string currentLine;
getline(cin, currentLine, ';');
```

Now, if you need to get just the last line with has the semi-colon, a loop is necessary, but still you can do it at little more easily.

```
string currentLine;
while(getline(cin, currentLine)){
    if(currentLine.find(";") != string::npos){
        break;
    }
}
```

Use strings to pass things around as well. There's always the `.clear()` method as well that any string has for easy emptying.

[string getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
[string Object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Answer (score 0):

To detect the EOF you should use something like:

```
while (cin.good() && !cin.eof())
{
    // Read the file
}
```

See the [documentation for cin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), in particular the [`good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) (for error checking) and [`eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) member functions.

In particular [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) might be helpful.